# How to filter https traffic in mod-security WAF?

Tags: tls, mod-security, waf

I'm developing a WAF with good GUI and better log. And my base firewall is mod-security. It works well for http but I also want to work my WAF with https. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you deployed Mod security as reverse proxy or apache plugin ?

Comment: @Ali, I deployed it as reverse proxy.

Comment: Follow this link http://adolfomaltez.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/apache-reverse-proxy-modsecurity/  and Read ModSecurity handbook

Comment: Thank you Ali sir. Your link is very helpful and I was searching for modsecurity handbook but couldn't find link to download for free.

Comment: You can read book from https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/modsecurity-handbook-getting-started-may-2012.pdf

Comment: Hi @DanielExar, welcome to [security.se]. When you get a chance, I recommend reading the [FAQ] and the [About page](http://security.stackexchange.com/about), if you haven't yet. Just to be clear, you are developing a UI for configuring mod-security, and not really developing a WAF yourself? What exactly is the problem you are having with HTTPS, is Apache not terminating the SSL connection before hitting mod-security?

Comment: @AviD thank you for welcoming me here. And my problem is i want my WAF to filter https traffic because mod-security defaultly filters http only.

Answer (score 2):

Terminate your SSL sessions as the very first thing you do at your reverse proxy / load balancer. Then feed the terminated sessions through your WAF, then to your regular daemon. Basically, you need to add another reverse proxy to the chain.